# How to sort list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

i want sort list bellow by price low to high

i want sort list bellow by price low to high 
i want sort list bellow by price low to high 
i want sort list bellow by price low to high 
i want sort list bellow by price low to high

```
getProductsList() {
    List list = [];
    list.add({
      "id": "1",
      "name": "sssss",
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/Frozen Food.jpg",
      "description": "qwerfghjhgfdsaasdfghnjmhgfdsa",
      "price": "11",
      "quantity": "1",
      "isLiked": "false",
      "max": "5"
    });
    list.add({
      "id": "2",
      "name": "sssss",
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/Frozen Food.jpg",
      "description": "qwerfghjhgfdsaasdfghnjmhgfdsa",
      "price": "112",
      "quantity": "1",
      "isLiked": "true",
      "max": "5"
    });
    list.add({
      "id": "3",
      "name": "sssss",
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/Frozen Food.jpg",
      "description": "qwerfghjhgfdsaasdfghnjmhgfdsa",
      "price": "114",
      "quantity": "1",
      "isLiked": "true",
      "max": "10"
    });
    list.add({
      "id": "4",
      "name": "sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssszzzzz",
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/Frozen Food.jpg",
      "description": "qwerfghjhgfdsaasdfghnjmhgfdsa",
      "price": "11",
      "quantity": "1",
      "isLiked": "false",
      "max": "1"
    });
    list.add({
      "id": "5",
      "name": "sssss",
      "imageUrl": "assets/images/Frozen Food.jpg",
      "description": "qwerfghjhgfdsaasdfghnjmhgfdsa",
      "price": "110",
      "quantity": "1",
      "isLiked": "false",
      "max": "15"
    });
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried not a sample of the list want to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
list.sort((a, b) => a['price'].compareTo(b['price']));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-:

```
 list.sort((ListModel a,ListModel b)=>a.getprice().compareTo(b.getprice()));
```